# Derivative of fraction of vectors

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, quadratics

Hi is there anyone that can help me with this calculation? [image]

So, I don’t know the exact way to differentiate the fraction of vector function. I tried to use the formal way but the components of the numerator had different size of dimension. Btw I actually solved the question by Cauchy-Schwarts inequality but am just curious with the technique the solution suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
$

I assume that $x'$ means the transpose of $x$.

By differentiate, I assume they mean take gradient $\nabla_\alpha$. The facts we need are

1. The product rule holds. If $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$ are scalar-valued functions then
   $$
     \nabla_\alpha f(\alpha)g(\alpha)
       = (\nabla_\alpha f(\alpha))g(\alpha) + f(\alpha)(\nabla_\alpha g(\alpha)).
   $$
2. If $f : \R \to \R$ and $g : \R^n \to \R$ then the chain rule is
   $$
     \nabla_\alpha f(g(\alpha))
     = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\nabla g(\alpha).
   $$
3. If $x$ is a vector independent of $\alpha$ then
   $$
     \nabla_\alpha(\alpha'x) = \nabla_\alpha(x'\alpha) = x.
   $$

All together, we see
$$\begin{aligned}
  \nabla_\alpha\rho_{yw}^2
&= \frac{2(\alpha'\sigma_{yx})[\nabla_\alpha(\alpha'\sigma_{yx})]}{\sigma_{yy}(\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\alpha)}
  - \frac{(\alpha'\sigma_{yx})^2}{\sigma_{yy}(\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\alpha)^2}[\nabla_\alpha(\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\alpha)]
\\
&= \frac{2\alpha'\sigma_{yx}}{\sigma_{yy}(\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\alpha)}\sigma_{yx} - \frac{(\alpha'\sigma_{yx})^2}{\sigma_{yy}(\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\alpha)^2}[\nabla_\beta(\beta'\Sigma_{xx}\alpha) + \nabla_\beta(\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\beta)]
\\
&= \frac{2\alpha'\sigma_{yx}}{\sigma_{yy}(\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\alpha)}\sigma_{yx} - \frac{(\alpha'\sigma_{yx})^2}{\sigma_{yy}(\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\alpha)^2}[\Sigma_{xx} + \Sigma_{xx}']\alpha.
\end{aligned}$$
The first equality is application of the product rule followed by application of the chain rule in each term. The second equality is application of fact (3.) in the first term and application of the product rule in the second term. Finally, the third equality follows application of fact (3.) in the second term, noting that $\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\beta = (\Sigma_{xx}'\alpha)'\beta$.
I assume now that $\Sigma_{xx}$ is symmetric so that $\Sigma_{xx} + \Sigma_{xx}' = 2\Sigma_{xx}$. Setting $\nabla_\alpha\rho_{yw}^2 = 0$ and making the obvious cancellations gives
$$
  \sigma_{yx} = \frac{\alpha'\sigma_{yx}}{\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\alpha}\Sigma_{xx}\alpha
  \implies
  \alpha = \frac{\alpha'\Sigma_{xx}\alpha}{\alpha'\sigma_{yx}}\Sigma_{xx}^{-1}\sigma_{yx}.
$$

Comment: thank you so much for such a complete solution to the problem, I appreciate it

Comment: two more question, how am I sure that the solution of the above equation is the max value? do i need to determine by the second derivative? How can I answer the suspicion about the differentiability?

Comment: @bbq12340 Nothing simple jumps out at me. You could [look at second derivatives](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test), but that will get ugly very quickly.

Comment: I don't know what "suspicion of differentiability" you're referring to. If you just mean whether or not $\rho_{yw}^2$ is differentiable at all, it's a composition of differentiable functions (away from the obvious singularities), so it is also differentiable.

Comment: Thanks  it’s perfect